# How to run generated SQL from a variable?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I've tried running my SQL (in T-SQL) (I just genereated into a variable) but I can't get it to run.
What I want to do is:
1. Run big SQL from Program
2. Big SQL generates selct-SQL
3. run generated sql like normal select and receive data like normal.
I thought it could be done done with [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) but it looks like it's not right in my case.

What I'm trying looks like this:

```
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = 'select x, y from z'

exec @sql --this is the point where im stuck.
```

I know this must be quite a basic question, but I couldn't find something that fits to my problem on google.

Thanks for your help!

*Update*
I solved my problem by using sp_sqlexec (which isn't supported anymore but works like I wanted).

```
declare @sql varchar(max)

set @sql = 'select x, y from z'

exec sp_sqlexec @sql
```

The correct solution is sp_executesql! (see [sp_sqlexec vs. sp_executesql](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlgetstarted/thread/554d6373-8a22-4b10-8744-df13e5415f84))
For my problem it would be quite time consuming if i would "rebuild" everything that I could use it.

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need parentheses `exec (@sql)`

SQL Server will look for a stored procedure of the name in the `@sql` variable without this and complain `Could not find stored procedure 'select x, y from z'.`

If you are using dynamic SQL See [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for a good article on the topic.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `sp_executesql`, but note that it needs NVARCHAR (Unicode)

Also, if you are building dynamic filters, you can pass in parameters as per below

```
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL = N'select x, y from z where x = @someFilter'
exec sp_executesql @SQL, N'@someFilter bigint', @someFilter = 6034280
```