# Weird error on stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Here is my dynamic sql in a stored procedure

```
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @SQL as varchar(4000)

set @SQL = 'CREATE VIEW vw_GCS_Export
    As
    select division, [primary image id],[Item Number], [Brand Name],[Marketing Description],
    [Colours]as Colors,[Live Date],[Sample Type],substring([FileName],charindex('+ CHAR(39) + '_' + CHAR(39) +',[FileName],1)+1,CHARINDEX('+ CHAR(39) + '.' + CHAR(39) +',[FileName],1)-5) as BatchID,
    '+ CHAR(39) + '670' + CHAR(39) +' as Status, [Primary image ID] + '+ CHAR(39) + '_P' + CHAR(39) +' as [Shot Name],
    Cast(Null as varchar(50))as [Swatch/Variation],Cast(Null as varchar(50))as [Alternate Shot],[UserName],''' + CAST(convert(date,Sysdatetime(),110)as varchar(10)) + ''' as [Import Date],
    Cast(Null as varchar(50))as [Return Instructions],Cast(Null as varchar(50))as [Rush Request], DATEADD(WEEKDAY,-5,[live date]) as [ImageDeliveryDate],
    '  + convert(varchar(50), ' + ' +  CHAR(39) + 'Division ' + CHAR(39) +' + [Division] + '+ CHAR(39) + ' * ' + CHAR(39) +' + [UserName] ) as JobName 
    from Sheet1$'


EXEC @SQL
select * from vw_GCS_Export

END
```

I am getting an error on execution

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'EXEC'.
```

I am not sure why. I don't seem to have any errors inside the SQL statement.

Comment: I don't think that's the root cause of the problem - but the string you pass to `EXEC()` should be of type `NVARCHAR` (not `VARCHAR`)

Answer (score 5):

You need parentheses:

```
EXEC (@sql)
```

See [How to run generated SQL from a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872959/how-to-run-generated-sql-from-a-variable)

Comment: I added the parentheses with the same result.  I have done this format before but never had an issue.  it is almost like the sql statement is not ending.

Comment: @TimVavra Can you test if [this](http://pastebin.com/T20NQVv4) works for you?

Answer (score 2):

Your actual issue is here:

```
 '  + convert(varchar(50), '
```

You have a `CONVERT` without a second argument.  It could be you meant to include either the `CONVERT` in the dynamic SQL or you meant to have this part

```
' + [UserName] ) as JobName
```

as the end of your `CONVERT` but in either case, it doesn't compile and your syntax is busted.

Comment: I made the corrections you suggested and it still produces the same error.  I have a copy of the stored procedure without the convert that operates fine except for the float error.  Is this simply a implicit conversion that I could turn off?

Comment: @TimVavra it sounds like you have other issues in your string creation syntax.  You are going to need to step through piece by piece to see what is causing the problem, and SO is really not a place for that - this is a problem in **your** query that will never help anyone else since it's based on something specific to your situation.  You just need to step through it to fix it.

Comment: okay I know where the error is I am just unable to figure out the correct syntax.

Comment: @TimVavra If you know where the issue is then update the question with the specifics.

Comment: @JNK I was able to isolate the problem because the convert statement was added to a stored procedure that already operated.  The ultimate solution was to convert only the float variable in the statement.  Apparently if you have multiple data types in a concatenation, you cannot convert multiple different data types within a single convert statement.  Once I changed the convert to affect only the [Division] field, the statement worked.  I hope this clarifies the issue and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I ended up with:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @SQL as varchar(4000)

set @SQL = 'CREATE VIEW vw_GCS_Export
    As
    select division, [primary image id],[Item Number], [Brand Name],[Marketing Description],
    [Colours]as Colors,[Live Date],[Sample Type],substring([FileName],charindex('+ CHAR(39) + '_' + CHAR(39) +',[FileName],1)+1,CHARINDEX('+ CHAR(39) + '.' + CHAR(39) +',[FileName],1)-5) as BatchID,
    '+ CHAR(39) + '670' + CHAR(39) +' as Status, [Primary image ID] + '+ CHAR(39) + '_P' + CHAR(39) +' as [Shot Name],
    Cast(Null as varchar(50))as [Swatch/Variation],Cast(Null as varchar(50))as [Alternate Shot],[UserName],''' + CAST(convert(date,Sysdatetime(),110)as varchar(10)) + ''' as [Import Date],
    Cast(Null as varchar(50))as [Return Instructions],Cast(Null as varchar(50))as [Rush Request], DATEADD(WEEKDAY,-5,[live date]) as [ImageDeliveryDate],
    ' + CHAR(39) + 'Division ' + CHAR(39) +'+ cast([Division] as varchar(50)) + '+ CHAR(39) + ' * ' + CHAR(39) + ' + [UserName] as JobName 
    from Sheet1$'


    EXEC (@SQL)
    select * from vw_GCS_Export
```

The key is that I could not use the cast on the entire string, I only could put it on the float field [Division].  I appreciate all the help FreshPrinceofSO